# Why $A \subseteq \mathscr P(A)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Suppose $A ⊆ \mathscr P (A).$ Prove that  $\mathscr P(A) ⊆ \mathscr P
> ( \mathscr P(A)).$

How can you suppose that $A \subseteq \mathscr P(A)$?

If my understanding is correct, $\mathscr P(A)$ denotes power set of $A$, or in other words, set that contains all the subsets of $A$

Let $A = \{1,2\}$, then $\mathscr P(A) = \{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$

$\{1,2\}$ is *not* a subset of $\mathscr P(A)$, but $\{\{1,2\}\}$ is. We can only say that $A \in \mathscr P(A)$

So again, given that $\mathscr P(A)$ denotes power set of $A$, how is it possible to assume that $A \subseteq \mathscr P(A)$?

Comment: Is this from a book or a homework? Seems like someone just mistyped. Or... it's fine the way it's written and the antecedent is just false. Nothing wrong with proving a conditional with a false antecedent.

Comment: It is from the book "How to Prove It"

Comment: $A$ is an element of its power set, not a subset.

Comment: In other words, $A \subseteq \mathscr P(A)$ is false, but $A \in \mathscr P(A)$ is true. Correct?

Comment: These comments are very misleading. $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ is a reasonable assumption to make. It is saying that *under the assumption* that $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$, the consequence $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ follows.

Comment: I suspect the symbol $A$ got overloaded and the statement is supposed to be "Suppose $B \subseteq \mathcal P(A)$. Prove that $\mathcal P(B) \subseteq \mathcal P(\mathcal P(A))$."

Comment: @UmbertoP: Why do you think that? The exercise as stated is a perfectly reasonable thing to ask someone to prove.

Comment: @Nelver : Yes, if $\mathcal{P}[]$ denotes power set then the statement should be corrected to "Suppose $A \in \mathcal{P}[A]$, prove $\mathcal{P}[A] \in \mathcal{P}[\mathcal{P}[A]]$." As Robert Wolfe mentions, this is just a typo in the book.

Comment: @Michael: Yet another misleading comment! There is nothing wrong with the assumption $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$. [In fact, making the assumption $A \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ would be redundant since it's always true.]

Comment: @Nelver : On the other hand if $\mathcal{P}:V\rightarrow V$ denotes some operator on a set $V$ (so that it does _not_ represent the power set) then the problem would make more sense.  [That is because it is always true that $A$ is an element of the power set of $A$, we would not need to "suppose" it.]

Comment: "A is an element of its power set, not a subset. "  It *can* be.  It isn't in general, but there are sets that are.  "In other words, A⊆P(A) is false, but A∈P(A) is true."  $A\in\mathscr P(A)$ is always true.  But $A\subset \mathscr P(A)$ depends upon what set $A$ is.

Comment: Clive's Answer gave three examples where $A \subset \mathscr A$ was perfectly true.  $\emptyset\subset \{\emptyset\}=\mathscr P(\emptyset)$ and $\{\emptyset\}\subset\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} = \mathscr P(\{\emptyset\})$.

Comment: @CliveNewstead : Your comment to me arrived between two of my own. I ultimately suggested  $P:V\rightarrow V$ can denote a function (not the power set). Indeed for any $f:V\rightarrow V$ we have
$$ A\subseteq f(A) \implies f(A) \subseteq f(f(A))$$ with the convention $f(A) = \{f(a) : a \in A\}$.  So I thought this was the likely meaning. My first comment intended to validate Nelver's observation that, if  $P=2^A$ 
denotes power set, then statement $A \in 2^A$ is syntactically correct.  [Statement $A\subseteq 2^A$  appears to be a typo or syntax error  but as you point out it can make sense.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it makes matters less confusing, an equivalent way of stating the problem is:

> Let $A$ be a set. Prove that if $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$, then $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$.

This doesn't mean that $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ is true for all sets $A$; it just means that for the set $A$ being discussed, the assumption is made that $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$, in order to derive the conclusion that $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$.

And indeed $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ is a reasonable assumption to make. For example, it's true when $A = \varnothing$ or $A = \{ \varnothing, \{ \varnothing \} \}$ (or any other [von Neumann ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Von_Neumann_ordinals)) or [$A = V_{\omega}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe), or more generally any ([pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_set)) [transitive set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set).

The fact that you found a counterexample to the hypothesis just means that the conclusion of the theorem doesn't apply to that set.

Answer (score 2):

First consider $A_0 = \mathbb{N}$ and $A_n = \mathscr{P}(A_{n-1})$. Then consider $B = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{A_n} \dots$

For your question, suppose $x \in \mathscr{P}(A)$. Then $x \subset A$  . But then $x \subset A \subset \mathscr{P}(A) $ and indeed $x \in \mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(A)) $.